# Can leaving a Catch block empty cause issues in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I'm working on a large code base and trying to refactor a bunch of old javascript code. My boss pointed out that there are a lot of `try{ }catch(err){ }` blocks in the code where the developer left the `catch` block empty.

Anyhow, is there any harm in leaving these blocks of code empty? I've heard it can causes issues in Java, but is there any harm in the case of JavaScript.

Example:

```
try {
      if (value != null) {
       var typeOne = report;
       returnVal = formatB;
     }
 } catch (err) {
    // Is this bad?
 }
```

Comment: not an answer, but a suggestion: why not replacing the comment with console.log('error: ' + err) ?

Comment: That's basically what I did, I was just curious if it could cause issues

Comment: `I've heard it can causes issues in Java` no, not really. Not much more than in JavaScript, at least - any potentially useful information will be swallowed in either case, so the only issue is that you will have a hard time knowing if something went bad or not. Sometimes you might be happy to swallow the exception but etiquette/standards usually dictate that you leave a comment to tell future maintainers that it's intentional.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've seen in most languages I've worked with, empty Catch blocks swallow errors and make debugging really tricky. It would be kinder to log the exception somewhere, or throw it to the UI level in an error message, or to an error-handling method where it's treated appropriately, at least in my experience. Otherwise you may end up with buggy behavior and have a load of difficulty tracking it down.

Comment: So basically it squashes any errors. That makes sense.

Comment: That's what I've seen, right -- it's like the errors just disappear into a black hole. :) We encountered this problem at work this week with a legacy project and started rewriting the Try/Catch blocks to handle the exceptions better.